# How to update bound control to object by setting ObjectA = ObjectB

Tags: vb.net, object, data-binding

I have an object that has properties that are also objects and are bound to a textbox. I would like to be able to just set MyOriginalObj = MyNewOject and have the textbox display the new value. This does not work. What I have to do is MyOriginalObj.PropertyA = MyNewObj.PropertyA. This will cause the textboxes to update.

I would like to avoid the latter method because my actual class has many more properties than my test class below and would increase the code needed to do all the updates. If I have to I think I could just unbind and bind to the new object but again that is adding more code. The MyOriginalObj = MyNewObj  method will be the simplest solution but I am not sure if it is possible. Please advise.

```
Dim fam As New Family

Public Class Person

    Dim _Age As Integer = 0
    Dim _Name As String = ""

    Public Property Age() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Age
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Age = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal age As Integer, ByVal name As String)

        With Me
            ._Age = age
            ._Name = name
        End With

    End Sub

End Class
```

-

```
Public Class Family

    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
          ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
          Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Dim _Father As New Person(0, "")
    Dim _Mother As New Person(0, "")

    Public Property Father() As Person
        Get
            Return _Father
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Person)
            _Father = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, 
                New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Father"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Mother() As Person
        Get
            Return _Mother
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Person)
            _Mother = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, 
                New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Mother"))
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

-

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", fam, "Father.Name")
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", fam, "Mother.Name")

End Sub
```

-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Method A - works, textboxes displays the new values.
    ' fam.Father = New Person(30, "Joe")
    ' fam.Mother = New Person(29, "Jane")
    ' Exit Sub

    ' Method B - does not update textboxes.
    Dim fam2 As New Family
    fam2.Father = New Person(40, "Bob")
    fam2.Mother = New Person(39, "Betty")

    ' I would like the updated properties to be shown in the bound 
    ' textboxes when I set fam = fam2.  Object fam will contain 
    ' the new values but the textboxes will not reflect that.
    fam = fam2
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1} : {2}, {3}", _
                      fam.Father.Name,  _
                      fam.Father.Age,  _
                      fam.Mother.Name,  _
                      fam.Mother.Age)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a method inside your `family` class that would achieve what you are looking for.

```
Public Class Family

  . . .

  Public Sub ReplaceFamily(newFamily As Family)
    With newFamily
      Me.Father = .Father
      Me.Mother = .Mother
    End With
  End Sub

End Class
```

Your call would look like:

```
fam.ReplaceFamily(fam2)
```

If you have a lot of properties in `family`, you could use reflection inside the `ReplaceFamily` method instead of setting each property individually.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to load and deserializing an xml file from disk. At the app start-up I am going to create an instance of Family with default values then bind that instance to the controls. Then whenever I load a new xml file I'll pass that new Family object in to the ReplaceFamily method and the bound controls will reflect the new data. Once I figure out to implement reflection the additional  code to make this work should be minimal. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveZuranski, Good luck with your project